# Mount a bucket using S3FS doesn't work as non-root user

Tags: s3fs

I'm trying to mount an [Exoscale](https://www.exoscale.com/) bucket to an Exoscale VM running Ubuntu 20.04 using [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) as the `ubuntu` user created by default by Exoscale. After reading the s3fs README and a few online tutorials here what I have done.

```
# install s3fs
sudo apt-get install -y s3fs

# create a password file with the right permissions
echo API-KEY:API-SECRET > /home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs
chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs

# mount the bucket
sudo mkdir /home/ubuntu/bucket
sudo s3fs test-bucket /home/ubuntu/bucket -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs -o url=https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io
```

The command doesn't output anything.
if I try to see the rights on the directory I get

```
$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'bucket': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bucket
```

If I try to run it with debug output enabled, I get

```
sudo s3fs test-bucket /home/ubuntu/bucket -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs -o url=https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io -o dbglevel=info -f -o curldbg
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [INF]
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4400): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=40775)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3493): init v1.86(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3828): check services.
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/test-bucket/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://test-bucket.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io
*   Trying 194.182.177.119:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test-bucket.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io (194.182.177.119) port 443 (#0)
* found 414 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL,CN=*.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io
*    start date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=FR,ST=Paris,L=Paris,O=Gandi,CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test-bucket.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io
User-Agent: s3fs/1.86 (commit hash unknown; GnuTLS(gcrypt))
Accept: */*
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=EXO6ff92566c0d6283678d65a81/20201209/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=22c63079ecfa9bf2f36f1da8e39835172bb1ce3cc59d62484cc0377c854571d4
x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date: 20201209T141053Z

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: nginx
< date: Wed, 09 Dec 2020 14:10:53 GMT
< content-type: application/xml
< content-length: 262
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-bucket-region: bg-sof-1
< x-amz-request-id: 8536e881-5897-4843-b20e-891f734ccb2a
< x-amzn-requestid: 8536e881-5897-4843-b20e-891f734ccb2a
< x-amz-id-2: 8536e881-5897-4843-b20e-891f734ccb2a
<
* Connection #0 to host ubuntu-bucket-production-120920.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io left intact
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2416): HTTP response code 200
[INF] curl.cpp:ReturnHandler(318): Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
```

Which doesn't output any evident error.

Am I missing anything here?  .

Doing the same as `root` works as expected. However, I'm planning to disable root access so I need to make it work as `ubuntu`.

Comment: Could you mount the bucket with `-d` to see what errors it has?

Answer (score 4):

To make it work, I had to add the following options:

```
sudo s3fs test-bucket /home/ubuntu/bucket -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs -o url=https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io -ouid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,mp_umask=002
```

Hope this may help others.

Comment: Would like to note the uid=1000 is "ubuntu" and gid=1000 is "ubuntu" in ubuntu machines at AWS.